# Signalr connection.start.done not firing

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, client, signalr, microsoft-edge

In my javascript code I call .start and stop a couple of times because I have to change the user's identity after the first connection if they exist on my server. The first time I call it, the server fires the expected code.

The second time it never enters the .done or .fail function of the .start call in IE and Edge, but only on our live test server. On my local IIS express it works as intended.

For reference, on the live test server we are using cross domain for the signalr server, but it works as intended on firefox and chrome.

EDIT:
It appears only to be after authentication. So if I start the connection without leaving page, I can chat using the client. But its not until I'm no longer authenticated that I can get it to work correctly again after leaving the page or refreshing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.

For future reference it had to do with a call I was making to the server before I called stop. I guess that call never finished and it was causing some errors. I fixed it by adding a .done function to the call I was making before the stop